# Is it possible to get build number even if build is unstable but not failed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When building a job in a scripted pipeline, I would like to keep the external build number even if that build is unstable but not failed.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Job1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    Job1 = build job: 'Job1'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Job2') {
            steps {
                  build job: 'Job2',
                            parameters: [
                                    string(
                                            name: 'Job1_ID'
                                            value: "${Job1.number}"
                                    )
                            ]
                }
          }
     }
}
```

I have tried with a **catchError()** around the job1 build, but still have that problem if the build is unstable.
I have also tried with `propagate:false` parameter, but I can never see the actual status of the build visually, plus, I don't want the second build to be triggered if the first is failed.
Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set `propagate: false` and then conditionally execute your second Job. Please see the pipeline below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Job1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    Job1 = build job: 'Job1', propagate: false
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Job2') {
            when { expression { return Job1.resultIsBetterOrEqualTo("SUCCESS")}}
            steps {
                  build job: 'Job2',
                            parameters: [
                                    string(name: 'Job1_ID',value: "${Job1.number}")
                            ]
                }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: The thing is here, imagine that the job 1 is a crucial job like a compilation one, I would never receive an email notification that the compilation job is failing. Or simply visually, I wouldn't be able to see the actual status of the job. I am trying to find something between a catcherror() and a propagate: false.

Comment: @twlch If you look at the answer you can check the status of Job1 with `Job1.resultIsBetterOrEqualTo("SUCCESS")`. SO based on this you can do whatever makes sense for your requirement.